# Kdenlive won't show the red audio Record button on Audio tracks

Tags: audio, recording, kdenlive

In kdenlive, I right click on the left end of an Audio track and select Show Record Controls, but the red button doesn't show up to enable recording with my microphone.
I have installed `libqt5multimedia5-plugins` using:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libqt5multimedia5-plugins
```

When I right click on an Audio track and select Configure Recording there is a long list of Devices that I can choose from, including default, pulseaudio, alsa:default, etc. But it doesn't matter which Device I select, the red button still doesn't show to let me record sound.
I can record with my microphone using the gnome Sound Recorder application.
This worked fine on previous versions of Kdenlive. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.02 and kdenlive 19.12.3.
I would appreciate any help.

---

UPDATE:

I upgraded to Kdenlive 20.12.3 using Ubuntu Software. The red button shows up now when I right click on a Sound Track and select Show Record Controls.
However, When I click the red button to record, an error pop-up reports "Cannot open file /home/.../capture0008.wav. Two files are created, when I click to Record and when I click to Stop. The .wav file names increment each time I try. All of the .wav files are 485 bytes and are corrupt according to other programs that play sound files.

I can record with my microphone using Audacity. Then add the .wav files to Kdenlive, as a workaround.
I will use the workaround for now and hope someone can provide helpful information. Since the Kdenlive update made some difference, I may try updating again with the PPA 21.04.1.

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Whew, I fixed it!
Here is the essence of what I did (I didn't include steps that I don't think were relevant).

Installed the latest version of Kdenlive, 21.04.02.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
sudo apt install kdenlive
```

Kdenlive's audio recording was still broken. I noticed that ubuntu now had 2 verions of Kdenlive showing in Applications. I removed them both with the Ubuntu Software tool, then ran:

```
sudo apt-get purge kdenlive
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
sudo apt install kdenlive
```

Fixed! In a nutshell, I purged the existing Kdenlive version(s). Then installed the latest PPA.